# How to left align latex equation in R Shiny app?

Tags: css, r, shiny, mathjax

I am working on a shiny App. I have inserted an equation using `withMathJax()`. I want to left align the equation and change the font to "Arial". Can anyone help?

Below is the sample problem:

```
library(shiny)


ui  <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("hello"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("formula")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
   output$formula <- renderUI({
    listcat <- c("Men","Ladies")
   value <- 15
    withMathJax(paste0("$$\\frac{",listcat[1], "\\cap ", listcat[2],"}{",listcat[1],"} =", value,"$$"))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS to align the formula:

```
div.MathJax_Display{
   text-align: left !important;
}
```

Note: Use `!important` to ensure the parameter is not overwritten

Then use

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("...")))
```

to insert it the shiny app.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("hello"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    div.MathJax_Display{
                    text-align: left !important;
                    }
  "))
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("formula")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$formula <- renderUI({
    listcat <- c("Men","Ladies")
    value <- 15
    withMathJax(paste0("$$\\frac{",listcat[1], "\\cap ", listcat[2],"}{",listcat[1],"} =", value,"$$"))
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that Arial is not supported by MathJax, see here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html.